# Javascript rotation incrementation

Tags: javascript, rotation, increment

Hello I am trying to increment a rotation by 90deg each time i click a anchor tag I am having some trouble, this is my code:

```
    var deg = 0;
    document.getElementById('main_photo').style.setProperty("-webkit-transform","rotate("+ deg +90 +"deg)", null);
```

Comment: What is your trouble? Does this only have to work in WebKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rotate("+ deg +90 +"deg)"`

Change that to

`rotate("+ (deg + 90) +"deg)"`

In javascript, string + number is a string. Thus, you want to add your numbers inside parentheses.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still having the same problem where it will only rotate by 90deg, and I wish for it to keep on rotating by 90deg each click.

Comment: So...just add 90 + it's current value.